# InvalidPathException - Downgrade to 8.4.0 or Workaround

Tags: drools, quarkus, optaplanner

I just started out a new project with Optaplanner and as soon as I started to build my constraints I get "InvalidPathException: Illegal char  at index 4:" which is a known bug in drools.

I read from someone at Stackoverflow that this bug was introduced somewhere after 8.4.0 Final so I am wondering how I successfully downgrade my version to that one.
I am currently using:

- Optaplanner 8.8.0 Final
- Quarkus 2.0.2 Final
- Open JDK 11
- Windows 10

I did try setting the dependency in the POM-file like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
  <artifactId>optaplanner-quarkus</artifactId>
  <version>8.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
  <artifactId>optaplanner-quarkus-jackson</artifactId>
  <version>8.4.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I do I get this exception and to be quite honest, I have no idea even where to start troubleshooting or what to try to solve this.

```
 org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.gizmo.GizmoMemberAccessorFactory.usePregeneratedMemberAccessorMap(Ljava/util/Map;)V
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:106)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter$ResteasyResponseWrapper.service(ResteasyFilter.java:70)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter$ResteasyResponseWrapper.sendError(ResteasyFilter.java:76)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:172)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter.doFilter(ResteasyFilter.java:31)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:63)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:67)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:65)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:56)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:111)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:108)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:587)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:152)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$1.handleRequest(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:119)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:290)
        at io.undertow.server.DefaultExchangeHandler.handle(DefaultExchangeHandler.java:18)
        at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$5$1.run(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:413)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:481)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2442)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1476)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.optaplanner.core.impl.domain.common.accessor.gizmo.GizmoMemberAccessorFactory.usePregeneratedMemberAccessorMap(Ljava/util/Map;)V
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.gizmo.OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation.setup(OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation.zig:35)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.gizmo.OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation_Subclass.setup$$superforward1(OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation_Subclass.zig:89)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.gizmo.OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation_Subclass$$function$$1.zig:24)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.gizmo.OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation_Subclass.setup(OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation_Subclass.zig:145)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.gizmo.OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation_ClientProxy.setup(OptaPlannerGizmoInitializer$Implementation_ClientProxy.zig:155)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider.solverFactory(OptaPlannerBeanProvider.java:52)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_Prthod_solverFactory_ebf4e4a597d923cd2db0f0f5ac4206b6dba0ce58_Bean.create(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_ebf4e4a597d923cd2db0f0f5ac4206b6dba0ce58_Bean.zig:255)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_ebf4e4a597d923cd2db0f0f5ac4206b6dba0ce58_Bean.create(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_ebf4e4a597d923cd2db0f0f5ac4206b6dba0ce58_Bean.zig:279)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_ebf4e4a597d923cd2db0f0f5ac4206b6dba0ce58_Bean.get(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_ebf4e4a597d923cd2db0f0f5ac4206b6dba0ce58_Bean.zig:311)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_ebf4e4a597d923cd2db0f0f5ac4206b6dba0ce58_Bean.get(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverFactory_ebf4e4a597d923cd2db0f0f5ac4206b6dba0ce58_Bean.zig:327)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.create(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.zig:236)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.create(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.zig:288)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.get(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.zig:320)
        at org.optaplanner.quarkus.OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.get(OptaPlannerBeanProvider_ProducerMethod_solverManager_d6636211e93ca3985f0495d972987bdadf803f37_Bean.zig:336)
        at org.schedulingservices.services.solver.SolverService_Bean.create(SolverService_Bean.zig:193)
        at org.schedulingservices.services.solver.SolverService_Bean.create(SolverService_Bean.zig:275)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.createInstanceHandle(AbstractSharedContext.java:96)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:29)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext$1.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ComputingCache.computeIfAbsent(ComputingCache.java:69)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AbstractSharedContext.get(AbstractSharedContext.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getApplicationScopedDelegate(ClientProxies.java:17)
        at org.schedulingservices.services.solver.SolverService_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(SolverService_ClientProxy.zig:67)
        at org.schedulingservices.services.solver.SolverService_ClientProxy.solve(SolverService_ClientProxy.zig:247)
        at org.schedulingservices.GreetingResource.hello(GreetingResource.java:30)
        at org.schedulingservices.GreetingResource_Subclass.hello$$superforward1(GreetingResource_Subclass.zig:157)
        at org.schedulingservices.GreetingResource_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(GreetingResource_Subclass$$function$$1.zig:24)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:49)
        at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(InvocationInterceptor_Bean.zig:521)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:50)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:127)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:100)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:53)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:26)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.zig:340)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
        at org.schedulingservices.GreetingResource_Subclass.hello(GreetingResource_Subclass.zig:213)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        ... 54 more
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to downgrade (or create a workaround for the problem with the latest final version?

Comment: I bet that there is an outdated dependency somewhere in the classpath. See `mvn dependency:tree` and look for OptaPlanner version other than 8.4.0.Final. That should give you a clue what you need to override.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks alot! Now i managed to downgrade my optaplanner version.
Do you know when the issue will be resolved? Always nice to stick to the latest version :)

Comment: Any day now. I am a bit surprised it is not fixed in 8.8.0.Final - in that case, 8.9.0.Final has to be it. The fix has been merged for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce with the recently released OptaPlanner 8.9.0.Final and was no longer able to. Please upgrade.

Comment: I still get the error. Just to be sure I ran a mvn dependency:tree to make sure all optaplanner references is pointing to 8.9.0 Final.